# Will initialize called by all subclasses?

Tags: objective-c, initialization

We know a method initialize that's called the first time an object is accessed.

Say I have a class, A whose child is B, C, D

Say, B, C, D is accessed (A is actually an abstract class).

Will [A initialize] be called?

Basically B, C, and D can have it's own initialize method but the methods are similar. So I am thinking of just putting it in A.

I do not intent to call initialize directly. I suppose I just got to call [super initialize]. What about if B doesn't have initialize at all. Will [A initialize] be called?

Answer (score 1):

If A has method initialize and you call `[B initialize]` when B did not implement such a method, then method initialize at A is called since B is a child of A.

Comment: I do not intent to call initialize directly. I suppose I just got to call [super initialize]. What about if B doesn't have initialize at all. Will [A initialize] be called?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do extra things in the subclass Initialize then you can do:

```
@implementation A
+(void)initialize
{
   // stuff you want to do for all of your subclasses
}
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
+(void)initialize
{
   [super initialize];
   // anything special for B
}
@end
```

If you only want the stuff in class A's initialize then see CodeHelps answer

Answer (score 0):

No, if you call directly

```
[B Initiliaze]
```

(where the "Initialize" method overwrite the Initialize of A), the method on A is not called.
If you need to call it you have to call it manually from the "B Initialize" method.

Comment: +initialize is a class method that the run time calls for you before the class is used, you don't call it yourself .

Answer (score 0):

`[A initialize]` is guaranteed to be called before `[B initialize]`. If class `B` does not implement `+initialize` itself, then the call to `[B initialize]` will run `A`'s `+initialize` implementation a second time (with `self == B`).

Comment: I am not asking whether [A initialize] will be called when [B initialize] is called. I am asking if [A initialize] is called when B is accessed for the first time.